# Keep Sublime from using 2 levels of "tabs"

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime on a Mac. I've found that it uses 2 layers of tabs depending on how I open a file (see screenshot).

[image]

- If I open a file using File->Open it will put it in the lower level of tabs (which is contained within one of the tabs at the top level)
- If I open a file by going to it in Finder, right clicking -> Open With -> Sublime Text, it will create a new top level of tabs.

I don't really find it useful to have things divided in 2 ways like this. I would like to only have the lower level of tabs, like the below (this is how it looks before you open a second tab at the top level, i.e. when there is only one top level it is hidden by default):

[image]

So my question is, how can I either disable the top level of tabs, or get it so that right clicking on a file and using "Open With" doesn't use the top level? I am new to Mac and I can't tell if the top level of tabs is something built into Mac OS or if this is a Sublime setting that I can change. But I haven't found what I need in the Sublime settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `System Preferences` -> `Dock` -> `Prefer tabs when opening documents` and select `Manually`. This will avoid the Mac OS tabs unless asked explicitly.

See also: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1434.

EDIT: Per the comments below, if you also want to ensure that the documents open in the same window (not a new window) you can follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023529/open-files-and-folders-in-same-window-in-sublime-text

Comment: This eliminates the tabs (when right clicking on a file and opening with Sublime) but it just ends up opening the document in a new window, even if I already have a window open. What I'd like is to open the document as a new "Sublime tab" in the existing window, the same as it does with File->Open.

Comment: @Stephen Well that's another question. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21023529/).

Comment: Awesome, that works, thank you! Giving you the bounty. BTW for some reason Mac doesn't switch to the Sublime window if it is minimized or maximized (only if it is in between) which I find strange, but close enough I guess.

Comment: @Stephen Does the workaround by Joshua1989 in [this issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/448) work for your case?

Comment: It does, mostly. You're the best! I added on to that thread and linked it from your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this in macOS Monterey? The `Prefer tabs [...] when opening documents` setting has moved to `System Preferences > General`, but it no longer has a `Manually` option.